# Android App Architecture : How should the packages be formed?

Tags: java, android, architecture

I am new to android programming. I often see that programmers create packages as collection of activities, fragments, adapters, etc. To me it seems more intuitive to put all java code required for an activity/screen in one place. For example: For home screen, I will keep the activity, fragments, adapters, custom views, etc all at one place.
Is there is any definite reason the the general practice or is it just a traditional practice ?

Comment: primarily opinion-based I think...

Comment: Its your code, you can structure it how you like to. As long as it has a structure ;)

Comment: I have explained [Pros and cons of  different package structures in Android apps](http://onetouchcode.com/2016/11/06/package-structure-android-apps/). This might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with creating components, reusable objects and code maintenance in a codebase as it grows. Your approach will work for a small application, and there is no rule against it. However, generally creating package/file structures according to the recommended and common approaches makes it easier to make modifications to code and work with others on the same project. Consider the following:

If you have many Activities spread across many packages or folders, then someone tasked with changing the UI will have to traverse those packages. That makes it difficult to identify UI patterns that could be used across `Activities` and even harder to use those patterns, since you will need to implement them in each package/folder.

This also creates a problem seeing less obvious patterns in non-UI components like data object models, view controllers, etc. For example, if you need a "user" object in two different `Activities` do you create 2 different objects? This is not reusable code.

So let's say you decide to reuse the "user" object so that you only have 1 class. Then do you sub-class in the other packages that need it in order to follow your pattern? Then if one UI element needs a new method, do you implement it in just that place? Or the base object?

Or do you make the "user" object public and reference it from other packages/folders? If this is your answer then you will begin to create objects in places based on the evolution of the code, instead of based on logic or ease of maintenance. Among other things, this makes it very difficult to train a new person on "where everything is" in your codebase. The "user" object will sit in one place, and then the "user account" object ends up where it is first needed, but not likely to be with the "user" object.

As a project grows to hundreds of classes, I think it is obvious that this approach becomes unmanageable for many applications. Classes will appear in packages based on the UI requirement, not based on the function it performs. Maintaining them becomes challenging.

For example in the case of Lollipop to Marshmallow, Apache http became deprecated. If you had this dependency scattered throughout your project, then you will be looking in a lot of places at how to handle this change. On a small project that might be fine, but on a larger project if you try to do this while other development is taking place, this can become a real mess since you are now modifying across many packages and folders instead of in only a few locations.

If, however, you have a Data Access Layer or Model Layer components that encapsulate the behavior in one or several folders, then the scope of your changes is easier to see to those around you. When you merge your changes into the project, it is easy for the people you work with to know if other components were impacted.

So while it is not necessary to follow these guidelines (especially for small projects), as a project grows and several or many people become involved in the development, you will see variations but the general practice is to group by purpose or function rather than group by UI / visual component. If you start off with some of this in place, you will have less work later to deal with the change. (However, starting with too much structural support early in a project can put the project at risk of never being completed...)

Several answers provides links to the guidelines. I hope this answer helps to explain why those guidelines exist, which I believe is at the heart of your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there is any definite reason the the general practice or is it just
>   a traditional practice ?

Yes. In my current application I have over 50 custom UI views and a few activities. At least 10 singleton controller and a lot of database model. So `to not lost` in the project, I'm using a tidy structure like this:

```
Activity
Adapter
Controller
Native
Model
-Database
-Rest
Ui
```

I suggest you to use this structure.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I found a structure based on MVC model. https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices

Comment: I think this is the best structure too.

Answer (score 1):

There are no official rules, well maybe best practices which I have not in mind.

I so we get now a opinion based answer:
I use the package names for grouping classes to a logical topic like adapters, activities, etc.

If you want another structure do it like you want, just it could confuse other devs.

Keep in mind that the package name should be unique so you should use a prefix like a domain you own or you are allowed to use (in reversed order of cause).

Check also this link where are some more ideas pointed out: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

> The first question in building an application is "How do I divide it up into packages?". For typical business applications, there seems to be two ways of answering this question.
>   **Package By Feature**
>   Package-by-feature uses packages to reflect the feature set. It tries to place all items related to a single feature (and only that feature) into a single directory/package. This results in packages with high cohesion and high modularity, and with minimal coupling between packages. Items that work closely together are placed next to each other. They aren't spread out all over the application. It's also interesting to note that, in some cases, deleting a feature can reduce to a single operation - deleting a directory. (Deletion operations might be thought of as a good test for maximum modularity: an item has maximum modularity only if it can be deleted in a single operation.)

Comment: I have been using the same practice as the article suggested. But I have seen most people use the other technique for no specific reason. Seems like more of a tradition.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the activities are places in the main package and fragments, adapters, utils, models in their own packages like fragments in fragments packages and ISODateParser class could go into utils package.

You can find more about it in the [Android Best Practices](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices) guide which contains best practices for android.

The guidelines about which classes should be placed under which packages are discussed under the *Java packages architecture* heading in the guide.

Hope it Helps!